# I need to start Apache using XAMPP, however Port 80 is blocked by a company service

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost, port

I'm writing a project using php and html. Since my project will be interacting with MySQL soon, I need to start it properly using XAMPP. However, the default port is occupied by a company service.

Our company has a service running on port 80, and I need to start Apache. Obviously this means, I need to overwrite the default port used by XAMPP. I think I've done that, however it still won't open my site.

I've changed the port in the httpd.conf file (80 to 123), and the httpd-ssl.conf file (443 to 8081). Additionally I've adjusted the Service and Port Settings from XAMPP itself to use 123 as the main port and 8081 as the SSL port.

The error message I get is as follows:
"The webpage at http://localhost:123/myFolder/myFile.php might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."
My myFolder is inside the xampp/htdocs folder and myFile inside of that.

I've also used netstat -ano -p tcp to see wether the ports had the right PID, and both adresses (0.0.0.0:123 and 0.0.0.0:8081 have the PID 4608, which is the same which the XAMPP Control Panel shows).

[image: A screenshot of my XAMPP Control Panel with just Apache running.]

Comment: In Chrome it will tell you that it has `ERR_UNSAFE_PORT`. Try using a number other than `123`. Maybe `1234`. List of unsafe ports (for Chrome): https://superuser.com/questions/188058/which-ports-are-considered-

Comment: @qrsngky Oh my god thank you o_o That was exactly it! :D

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure how to accept comments as answers, so I'll just post it here:
@qrsngky solved the issue for me. Apparently not all ports are supported by Chrome and result in an `ERR_UNSAFE_PORT` error. I simply had to change the port from 123 to 1234.